# Custom UICollectionViewLayout's layoutAttributesForElementsInRect does not override any method from its superclass in Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, swift2, uicollectionviewlayout

When migrating my project from Swift 1.2 to 2.0 I encountered a problem: I'm using a custom layout for my UICollectionView which works well in Swift 1.2. However, in Swift 2.0 there's an error saying `Method does not override any method from its superclass` when trying to override `layoutAttributesForElementsInRect` in the custom layout.

I attempted to delete the `override`, and now the error becomes `Method 'layoutAttributesForElementsInRect' with Objective-C selector 'layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:' conflicts with method 'layoutAttributesForElementsInRect' from superclass 'UICollectionViewLayout' with the same Objective-C selector`. And it left me clueless. Any help would be appreciated!

```
class CustomCollectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout {
    //...
    override func layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect: CGRect) -> [AnyObject]? {
        let attributes : NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
        for section in self.itemAttributes {
            attributes.addObjectsFromArray(
                section.filteredArrayUsingPredicate(
                    NSPredicate(block: { (evaluatedObject, bindings) -> Bool in
                        return CGRectIntersectsRect(rect, evaluatedObject.frame)
                    })
                )
            )
        }
        return attributes as [AnyObject]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have declared the wrong return type, which is why the compiler doesn't let you use `override`, and you're not *overloading* the method, either, because overloaded methods have to have different *parameter* types; it's not enough to have only a different return type. The correct signature for this method is `func layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(_ rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]?`.

And while we're at it, don't use `let attributes : NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()`. Not only is the type specifier `: NSMutableArray` redundant (because the compiler can infer the type from the right-hand side), but it's easier to use Swift's built-in `Array` instead. Just change it from a `let` (read-only) to a `var` to make it mutable. In other words, `var attributes = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()` is better.

Comment: Thank you so much, it now compiles and runs well! But it's now giving an error message in the debugging area `<Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.`. Do I have to be concerned about it?

Comment: I don't know. I just started to see that same error in one of my playgrounds yesterday. I've been ignoring it because everything seems to run just fine, but if it's happening in a production app that'd be something to investigate.